# How to get hold of the content?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have spent several hours now trying to figure out the expression language to get hold of the flowfile content.

Have a simple test flow to try and learn Nifi where I have:
GetMongo -> LogAttributes -> Put Slack

```
-----------------------LOG1-----------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
        Value: 'Wed Sep 28 23:58:36 GMT 2016'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
        Value: 'Wed Sep 28 23:58:36 GMT 2016'
Key: 'fileSize'
        Value: '70'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'filename'
        Value: '43546945658800'
Key: 'path'
        Value: './'
Key: 'uuid'
        Value: 'd1e10623-0e90-44af-a620-6bed9776ed62'
-----------------------LOG1-----------------------
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57ec27ec35a0759d54fb465d" }, "keyA" : "valueA" }
```

In the putSlack expression for test I have tried:

```
${flowfile.content}
${message}
${payload}
${msg}
${flowfile-content}
${content}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no expression language that accesses the content of the flow file. The attributes and the content are purposely stored very differently in order to facilitate moving around a Flow File that could represent a large payload. Expression language operates on attributes only.

The ExtractText processor can be used to extract the whole content of the Flow File into an attribute, just keep in mind that should only be done when you know the content will have no problem fitting in memory.

Comment: To add onto this, the Apache NiFi Expression Language (EL) Guide lists all of the EL functions and how to use them: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html

Comment: @Bryan can you little bit elaborate it please how to take the whole contents in attribute and also tell how to get back it again.Please need your reply Thanks

Comment: If you use the ExtractText processor and add a user-defined property, the name of the user defined property will become a flow file attribute, and the value of the property is a regular expression to apply to the content. So foo = .* will select all content and put it into an attribute called foo.

Comment: @BryanBende, I tried your solution, but I get this error "Unable to return a scalar value for the expression .*  for flow file". (I assigned foo = .* , also tried with foo = $.* ) both did not work

Comment: @ShreyaB was that error definitely from ExtractText? That sounds like an error from EvaluateJsonPath

Comment: @BryanBende Yes. It was because , I used .* instead of (.*) in the value field. Brackets were missing